# Why my div in display grid expand to cover all is available area?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to insert 2 buttons inside 2 divs.
All divs in my CSS have a display grid as assigned.

My question is why do the divs with class button-left and button-right expand to take all the space available, even if I did not tell them to have a width of 100% or width of 100vw?

To all other div I did specify to be 100vw but not this last one, so why do they keep expanding.

If I put display: block inside of them it works, but I don't understand why do I have to specify that in the first place?

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  display: grid;
  border: dotted 1px #ff0;
}
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(/../../media/index0.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: cover;
}
.div-container {
  border: solid 2px red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.div-top-row {
  border: solid 2px pink;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.div-bottom-row {
  border: dotted 3px green;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.copyrights {
  height: 5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.btn {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  box-shadow: unset;
}
.btn-gradient {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0.875rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1e92e6, #60fbd0 75%, #1c6599 150%);
  background-size: 300% 100%;
}
.btn-blank-blue {
  background: 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #1e92e6;
  color: #1e92e6;
}
.btn:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1e92e6, #60fbd0 75%, #1c6599 150%);
  background-size: 300% 100%;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  color: #22242f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/../../css/index.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/../../media/global0.ico" />
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div-container">
      <div class="div-top-row"></div>
      <div class="div-bottom-row">
        <div class="div-button-left">
          <button class="btn btn-gradient btn-blank-blue" onclick='window.open("https://www.gitbook.com/")'>Read Docs</button>
        </div>
        <div class="div-button-right">
          <button class="btn btn-gradient" onclick='location.href="dashboard.html"'>Enter App</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="copyrights">
        <p>© 2022 New Company Sample LLC - All rights reserved.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _but I don't understand why do I have to specify that in the first place?_ Because if you don't specify something, you're letting the browser make the decision for you. Browsers render content, it's our job as devs/designers/whatever to decide *how* the content gets rendered. If you don't want them to take up 100% of the width, specify the `width` attribute to whatever value you like.

Comment: @AStombaugh so by default in grid view do all elements fill 100% of the space all the time unless differently specified?

Comment: see Kameron's answer. You can also use the browser inspector to see how your elements are being calculated and who's doing the calculation (your site or the browser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration, determined by the number of each selector type in the matching selector.

You essentially answered your own question. `display: block;` works because that is the default `display` for `div`'s. You have `div { display: grid;}` which changes the default `display: block;` on **all** of your `div's`.

`display: grid;` will try to use all available space. Hence, why your buttons are stretched. I would either put the `grid` on only applicable `div`'s. Or, you could use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class like so:

```css
div:not(.div-button-right, .div-button-left) {
  display: grid;
  border: dotted 1px #ff0;
}
```

This will **exclude** the `div`'s defined in the `:not` pseudo-class of those styles.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  border: dotted 1px #ff0;
}
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(/../../media/index0.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: cover;
}
.div-container {
  display: grid;
  border: solid 2px red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.div-top-row {
  border: solid 2px pink;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.div-bottom-row {
  display: grid;
  border: dotted 3px green;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.copyrights {
  display: grid;
  height: 5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.btn {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  box-shadow: unset;
}
.btn-gradient {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0.875rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1e92e6, #60fbd0 75%, #1c6599 150%);
  background-size: 300% 100%;
}
.btn-blank-blue {
  background: 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #1e92e6;
  color: #1e92e6;
}
.btn:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1e92e6, #60fbd0 75%, #1c6599 150%);
  background-size: 300% 100%;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  color: #22242f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/../../css/index.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/../../media/global0.ico" />
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div-container">
      <div class="div-top-row"></div>
      <div class="div-bottom-row">
        <div class="div-button-left">
          <button class="btn btn-gradient btn-blank-blue" onclick='window.open("https://www.gitbook.com/")'>Read Docs</button>
        </div>
        <div class="div-button-right">
          <button class="btn btn-gradient" onclick='location.href="dashboard.html"'>Enter App</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="copyrights">
        <p>© 2022 New Company Sample LLC - All rights reserved.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```